# Average sales percentage per employee on their working days

Tags: spreadsheet

I'm starting with a spreadsheet where rows are days and columns employees (don't know if it's the best way) like this

```
+------------+-----+------+
|            | Joe | Jack |
+------------+-----+------+
| 13/03/2019 | 100 |  150 |
| 14/03/2019 | 100 |      |
+------------+-----+------+
```

This allows me to create a stacked bar chart showing sales per employee per day.

Now I need to rank the employees based on the average sales percentage they achieve. Eg. Jack only worked the 13/03 where he did 60%. Joe did 40% the 13/03 and 100% the next day so its average would be 70%.

I don't know much about spreadsheets; what would be the best way to get these results?

Comment: The 70% average could be misleading, depending on the definition.  Suppose, for example, Joe has the only sales on another day and the value is 2.  That would be 100%.  Do you really want that to count equally with the other days?  Another way to get the average, which would weigh things proportionally, is to subtotal the sales by employee for all applicable days.  Then calculate the percentage on the subtotals.

Comment: Sales vastly depends on week days so I don't want to penalize employees who work on quiet days.